# Not able to click anywhere on console.actions.google to test

Tags: actions-on-google, diagflow

I am trying to test my google assistant app which is there on diagflow. When I open google assistant simulator it says "test enabled " but then it fades out and doesn't allow me to click anywhere.

I also tried to say " talk to my test app" on actual device but it doesn't launch my application.

I have checked weebhook url and everything looks fine. Can you let me know what went wrong. It was working earlier.

[image: screenshot google assistant ap]

Comment: Got the resolution, you have to make sure your web and app activity setting via google/myaccount is enabled (true). It will work properly then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the resolution, you have to make sure your web and app activity setting via google/myaccount is enabled (true). It will work properly then

Answer (score 0):

Simply log out from your account. clear all the cookies and login again.